# What's the difference between protocol witness table and vtable in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand the difference between swift's vtable and witness table. In theory it should be the same mechanism allowing dynamic dispatch of class methods. Documentation of SIL contains two paragraphs suggesting that those differs. But it is a bit confusing for me.

So, what is exactly the difference between those two?

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding vtables as you say allow the dynamic dispatch of class methods.
This tables are generated in compile time.

Witness tables in the other hand allow the dynamic dispatch of generic types, therefore the table is different because it needs to map the generic entries to achieve the same result: dynamic dispatch. These tables have the information the compiler uses to "produce runtime dispatch tables". The information is not defined in compile time.
If you check in the documentation the witness table maps the base protocol, the methods it requires as well as its associated type and its protocol conformances (of the associated type).

Not sure if I understood your question correctly?